# Get webcam video in HTML and send to flask server via socketio

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, flask, webcam

I'm trying to capture webcam video in the client side and sent frames to the server to process it. I'm newbie in JS and I'm having some problems.
I tried to use OpenCV.js to get the data but I didn't understand how to get it, in Python we can make

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

and the frame is an 2d-array with the image, but how can I get each frame (as 2d array) to send using OpenCV.js?

I have this code on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onOpenCvReady() {
    cv['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {
        var socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log("Connected...!", socket.connected)
        });

        const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        video.width = 500;
        video.height = 400;

        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();

                })
                .catch(function (err0r) {
                    console.log(err0r)
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                });
        }

                    let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
                    let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

                    const FPS = 15;
                    function processVideo() {

                        let begin = Date.now();
                        cap.read(src);

                        handle_socket(src['data']);

                        // schedule next one.
                        let delay = 1000 / FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
                        setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
                    }
                    // schedule first one.
                    setTimeout(processVideo, 0);

        function handle_socket(src) {

            socket.emit('event', { info: 'I\'m connected!', data: src });

        }

    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this @vinicvaz

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
// Select HTML video element where the webcam data is
const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

// returns a frame encoded in base64
const getFrame = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    const data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    return data;
}


// Send data over socket
function handle_socket(data, dst) {
    socket.emit('event', data, function (res) {
        if (res !== 0) {
            results = res;
        }
    });
}

frame64 = getFrame()
handle_socket(frame64);
```